# Is there possibility to place Symfony partials in separate catalogs?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, symfony1, partials

I'm writing mailing module for mailing in Symfony. I genereate body of an email I use partials in a module templates folder - each has its plain text and html version.

I want to organise them in separate folders inside templates such as:

```
templates/delete-comment/_plain.php
templates/delete-comment/_html.php
...
templates/some-action/_plain.php
templates/some-action/_html.php
```

Is there a way to achieve this? Obviously I was trying so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried similar thing with no luck too. I am using a different approach to organize my email templates. I usually create a separate module for my email templates and use descriptive names for my partials. I end up with something like that:

```
email_templates/_delete_comment_plain.php
email_templates/_delete_comment_html.php
...
email_templates/_some_action_plain.php
email_templates/_some_action_html.php
```

Comment: Fairly rational I think. Thanks.